# How can I select records between two dates vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oracle

I made a simple program for a boarding house, and I want to select data from my Oracle database table name *tblTransaction* where the date is between the two `DateTimePickers` on my other form, named *FormTransaction*, then I want the info from the selected rows to show into my `listview`.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
Call connect()
 getsql("SELECT * FROM tblTransaction WHERE Trans_Date > '" &  
 CDate(FormTransaction.date1.Text) & "' AND Trans_Date <'" &
 CDate(FormTransaction.date2.Text) & "'")

    While dr.Read
        Dim lv As ListViewItem = lvTrans.Items.Add(dr("Transaction_Num"))
        With lv.SubItems
            .Add(dr("Boarder_ID"))
            .Add(dr("Trans_Date"))

        End With

    End While

    con.Close()
```

Comment: To be honest I would actually avoid using concatenated strings to build your SQL as you are.  You're far better off using [parameterised](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240337) queries and/or [stored procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm)

Comment: Agreing with Westie -- you would not then have to translate your dates into strings and back again, and you'd not be susceptible to SQL injection attacks, and you'd not be forcing the database to hard parse every query submitted to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date function in Oracle. In order to use it you need to identify what format the input string is in. Assuming it to be in 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'; you can try -

```
to_date(CDate(FormTransaction.date1.Text),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Comment: thank you for this, how exactly do I insert this to my code? I get the error on the line 'to_date' .

Comment: actually I do not know VB.net. but based on your code like how you kept the sql code in double quotes and vb code ouside it. likewise you can keep the given code.